# OUTLOOK VSTO: what is the result of Application.Session.GetItemFromID(entryid, null) when the entryid has changed?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Help newbie to outlook VSTO, and have inherited some code for an OUTLOOK addin.

in one method we are looking for a mailitem with this call.

theItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(argEntryID, null);

We had a bug in the addin during a MOVE item phase and thus the entryid that we stored is most likely no longer valid.

When we pass in a valid entryid I get back a proper MailItem, but when I pass in a bad entryid I get a caught exception stating "the operation failed"

The question is: Is that normal, is that what I should expect back?

Note: I am a newbie to c# and VSTO, so any answers will have to be very explicit.Don't assume I know something that I should. I am a Powerbuilder and t-sql programmer, not a c# programmer....just got forced to maintain this app....a bit scared....a production app, that saves the company huge amounts of money....

Chris

Comment: When you move the mail item from one location to another it changes its `EntryId`.